# Add taxonomy terms under one place in the admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

So I have created a custom taxonomy and two custom post types and each of these custom post types should be able to be part of a taxonomy term. Right now to add more terms I have to go to the tab beneath the custom post types. I would like to have a menu tab that's visible right away, not hidden beneath the CPT, and I only want one place where you can add more terms to my taxonomy. Is this possible with a plugin or can I easily extend the admin interface?

Comment: You mean it should be like same as Posts ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair a tab like posts yes, should be visible on the first screen in the admin section.

Comment: Please also attach screenshot of what is current status and What you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the admin interface by creating your own plugin. Check out the [plugin handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) to learn more about it. In particular have a look at the [administration menus](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/administration-menus/) sections.

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). This has many features available

Comment: I'm using it but I haven't found an option for what I'm looking for.